# Error when I open Spyder: pylsp >=1.7.2,<1.8.0 : 1.7.1 (NOK)

Tags: python

I tried to upgrade conda and spyder, but I encountered an issue.

I tried:

1. `conda update anaconda`
2. `conda install spyder=5.4.3`
3. `pip install pylsp-mypy`

I used option 1 in the spyder terminal first and then I used it in the conda prompt, I don't know if that caused the error.

How can I solve this issue?

[image: Error message]

Edit (temporal solution):

I used `conda install --revision 0`, and this fresh Anaconda installation, with the drawback of needing to install every package again. However, all environments created remain intact.

I don't know what happened, but when I write 1 and 2 in the prompt again, I got the same error. I don't know if is a version issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please use this instead:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-lsp-server
```