# I made the mistake of trying to update spyder in anaconda, should have known better and never try to update

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

> [You have missing dependencies!
> Mandatory:
> PYISP >=1.7.2,<1.8.0 : 1.7. 1 (NOK)
> Please install them to avoid this message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwaVL.png)

How do i go about this? I have tried to uninstall spyder through the anaconda navigator and reinstalling. I get the exact same message. Last time i made this mistake I had to add the standalone spyder version which worked great. Now i am on a new computer and wanted to give the conda environment another try, 45 minutes later i get a message from spyder to update (did it through conda install etc...). Now this. Id like to try to see if i can fix it without moving to the standalone version. Thank you for any help available :)

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling on in anaconda navigator to no avail. Last resort is to install standalone spyder, but would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I guess the obvious question is did you attempt to  update PYISP to 1.7.2

Comment: No i havent, I am abit unsure of how to go about that.. I was led to belive a big selling point of anaconda was that it was a all in one product with a plug and play gui that even a moron like me could use :)

Comment: Try the suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76019272/error-when-i-open-spyder-pylsp-1-7-2-1-8-0-1-7-1-nok To be honest, it seems a misleading message. I can't find any actual package PYLSP. It does appear to be related to this component of Spyder: https://github.com/spyder-ide/pyls-spyder. I would love to give my opinions on Anaconda but that would be off topic :)

Comment: In the end i got so frustrated that i uninstalled the whole conda environment and reinstalled only to have it mess up other parts of python on the pc, but now at least spyder (old version) is working, and unless there are major changes i think ill stick with that for now. Once i do update i will be sure to check out the suggested link, seems someone had the exact same problem! Thank you! I spent alot of time researching PYLSP, only to  realize it was PYISP i should be looking for. Couldnt find any pip commands or documentation though :( but Thank you ! ! Will save this link!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm adding a downvote to close as a duplicate because the question has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76019272/error-when-i-open-spyder-pylsp-1-7-2-1-8-0-1-7-1-nok

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that name of the package and what the package is actually called are different from each other.`pyls-spider` is not the thing you are having the problem with. `pylsp` stands for `python-lsp-server`.

Try entering this command on the Anaconda terminal:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-lsp-server
```

This command should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a situation where you are locked to only local repositories then change the above to:

```
conda install python-lsp-server
```

This avoids trying to do a secure connection to the anaconda source.